# How do I draw an X?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+, gdi

So I tried to draw an X:

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), 
                     this.Width + 20 - 50,  
                     20,  
                     this.Width + 25 - 50, 
                     10);

e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1),  
                     this.Width - 20 + 50,  
                     20,  
                     this.Width + 25 - 50, 
                     10);
```

But it looks like an Axe. No matter which values I put for the second line code, it's just not right.

Comment: The best option: take list of paper, draw rectangle and write coordinates in each corner... Otherwise there is not too many combinations of +/- for x coordinate to try all :)

Comment: Let me see if I can find a pen.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Good tip... unfortunately it didn't help me. Can't make a pen work if brain broken lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

10 x 10  X just add the position self

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1), 
                     1,  
                     1,  
                     10, 
                     10);

e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black, 1),  
                     1,  
                     10,  
                     10, 
                     1);
```

Comment: @se13013 just a note: do not ever create a new pen in each paint operation. Never! Seriously. Create it once and reuse it. In this case you may even pick Pens.Black directly. Did I say you should NEVER do it? It'll impact performance VISIBLY. to summarize: do not do it. Never do it... Lol

Answer (score 2):

```
DrawLine(pen, startPoint_X, startPoint_Y, stopPoint_X, stopPoint_Y);
```

Your both lines are same stopPoint coordinates so it will draw a V.
The second thing is the X coor of your second line is bigger than control's width so the start point of the second line will outside of your control